# Updating data in the firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do small apps containing firebase codes to learn more about it. so here I made a todo list app, I was able to add the tasks to the firebase and I was able to delete it, the problem I have is updating the status of the task (isComplete: Bool) I've no idea how to write firebase code to update data. almost all the tutorial I read was about the data uploaded to real-time database and I'm using the cloud so I couldn't figure it out. here I wrote this code so when the task is done and I select the cell the circle turn into checkmark.circle It's work but of course the database isn't updated..

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TodoCell

        if cell.isComplete == false{
           cell.doneButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
           cell.isComplete = true
  
       } else {
           cell.doneButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "circle")
           cell.isComplete = false

}
}
}
```

Adding tasks to firebase codes

```
    public func postTask(task:String, isComplete: Bool,
                            completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> ()) {
      guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
          return
      }
  
        let documentRef = db.collection(DatabaseService.itemsCollection).document()

        db.collection(DatabaseService.usersCollection).document(user.uid).
        collection(DatabaseService.tasksCollection).
        document(documentRef.documentID).setData(["task" : task,
                                                  "isComplete": isComplete,
                                                  "taskId": documentRef.documentID])
        { (error) in


        if let error = error {
          completion(.failure(error))
        } else {
          completion(.success(true))
        }
      }
    }
```

SnapshotListener

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(true)

        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            return
        }
        listener = Firestore.firestore().collection(DatabaseService.usersCollection)
      .document(user.uid).collection(DatabaseService.tasksCollection)
      .addSnapshotListener({ [weak self] (snapshot, error) in

          if let error = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self?.showAlert(title: "Try Again", message: 
               error.localizedDescription)
            }
          } else if let snapshot = snapshot {
            let task = snapshot.documents.map { TasksList($0.data()) }
            self?.todoItems = task
          }
        })
    }
```

based on @bkbkchoy answer I wrote these codes:

```
func updateTask(task: TasksList,
                isComplete: Bool,
                        completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> ()) {
  guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }

    db.collection(DatabaseService.usersCollection).document(user.uid)
   .collection(DatabaseService.tasksCollection).document(task.taskId)
   .updateData(["isComplete": isComplete]) { (error) in
          if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
          } else {
            completion(.success(true))
    }
  }
}
    
}
```

and under didSelectRow

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TodoCell
        
       let isComplete = false
       
        
        if task2.isComplete == false{
           cell.doneButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
           cell.doneButton.tintColor = .systemBlue
           cell.isComplete = true

       } else {
           cell.doneButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "circle")
           cell.doneButton.tintColor = .systemGray
           cell.isComplete = false


}
        updateStatus(isComplete: isComplete)

        
    }
       
   private func updateStatus(isComplete: Bool) {
        databaseService.updateTask(task: task2, isComplete: isComplete) 
          { [weak self] (result) in
              switch result {
              case .failure(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self?.showAlert(title: "Try again", message: error.localizedDescription)
                }
              case .success:
               break
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

but I got an error :

No document to update: project/todo-list/database/(default)/documents/users/jYZmghQeXodeF2/tasks/1

```
struct TasksList {
  let task: String
  let taskId: String
  let isComplete: Bool


}

extension TasksList {
  init(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.task = dictionary["task"] as? String ?? ""
    self.taskId = dictionary["taskId"] as? String ?? ""
    self.isComplete = dictionary["isComplete"] as? Bool ?? false
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `TasksList` contain (why not simply `Task`, one instance represents one task)?

Comment: @vadian I updated my question with the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach cannot work.

The cell is just the **view**, it shows the UI elements and their values, the data source is the **model** `TasksList` (why not simply `Task`).

Cells are reused and you will lose the `isCompleted` information in the cell when the user scrolls. You have to update the **model** and reload the **view**

First of all declare the **model** as `Task` and `isComplete` as `var`iable. According to the naming guidelines `task` should be `name` or `title` and `taskId` should be just `id`

```
struct Task {
  let task: String
  let taskId: String
  var isComplete: Bool
}
```

---

In `cellForRow` set the UI elements in the cell according to the model

```
let task = todoItems[indexPath.row]
let imageName = task.isComplete ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle"
cell.doneButton.image = UIImage(systemName: imageName)
cell.doneButton.tintColor = task.isComplete ? .systemBlue : .systemGray
```

In `didSelect` toggle `isComplete` in the model, reload the row and save the task

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    todoItems[indexPath.row].isComplete.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    let task = todoItems[indexPath.row]
    updateTask(task: task, isComplete: task.isComplete) { result in print(result) }
}
```

As the whole task is handed over, the second parameter `isComplete` is not needed in `updateTask`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to update documents in Cloud Firestore:

1. Rewrite a specific property using `setData`:

```html
db.collection(DatabaseService.usersCollection)
    .document(user.uid)
    .collection(DatabaseService.tasksCollection)
    .document(task.taskId)
    .setData(["isComplete": isComplete], merge: true)
```

Note: if you use `setData`, you must include `merge: true` to overwrite a single property on an existing document or else the whole document will be overwritten.

2. Use `updateData`

```html
db.collection(DatabaseService.usersCollection)
    .document(user.uid)
    .collection(DatabaseService.tasksCollection)
    .document(task.taskId)
    .updateData(["isComplete": isComplete]) { err in 
        if let err = err {
            print("error updating document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("doc successfully updated")
        }
    }
```

Firestore has some great documentation online. If you want to learn more about updating/adding data [here's a good place to start.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

Comment: I updated my question with the codes I wrote based on your answer and the error I got please check it out

Comment: The error you got indicates that the document wasn't created yet at that path. If you want to make an update and are unsure if the document exists or not, the safer path is to go with option 1 with `setData merge: true` route. With setData, it will create a document if the document doesn't exist OR merge it (when the merge flag is set) if the document already exists. 

You should only use update if you're confident the document exists or it will throw an error.

Comment: Thank you..the document is exists but i figured out what cause the error. :)

Comment: Oh glad you sorted it out! What was the issue?

Comment: task: TasksList when i use it under didSelectAtRow i got error that i can't use tasksList and i should use value insted, so i wrote variable var task2 = TaskList(task: "", taskId: "1", isComplete: false)